# Angular - Multiple calls to $http. How to manage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a call through $http for each element in an array. Which leaves me very unsatisfied as this array can be quite large, so the performance may not be very good.

This is my code:

```
 function UrlController($scope, $http) {

     $scope.Url = ["http://", "http://"];

     $scope.UpdateContent = function()
     {
       Angular.foreach($scope.Url, function(url){
              $http... // launch httpRequest for each element
       });
     }
 }
```

with websockets could solve the issue???

Thanks

Comment: Can you stringify the array, send it all back, re-encode on the server, and loop it and return JSON from that? So one big call rather than X small ones?

Comment: tymeJV yes its a good solution. Node would be adjusted well to the server In this case?

Comment: Node would work perfect, JS on the front, JS on the back :)